# WebAPI: Map mutiple URL to same action without using MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

I need to create following three end point URLs
    /test,
    /test/method1
    /test/method2

I would like to take `/test` and `/test/method1` as same - do same task.
For `/test/method2`, do some other action.

What are the different ways to achieve this? The one I tried is as below. It works for the first two URL but `/test/method2` does not worked - it gives 'Not Found' exception.

Due to some design concern, I could not use the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Finally, I got it.

I also needed to add more action Method2() in the Controller, then it worked as expected.

`/test - goes to action Method1()`
`/test/method1 - goes to action Method1()`
`/test/method2 - goes to action Method2()`